# Appropriate icon for "change"

Tags: icons, symbols, iconography

I would like to change an icon symbolizing change with something more appropriate. Currently the icon is a star. After giving it some thought I realized that I didn't have a good concept of what symbolizes change (differences, not coinage).

I had thought of using arrows, but most designs reminded me of recycling, refreshing, or forward and back.

Edit for clarification:

I'm updating an icon used in a bug-tracking app for "change" tickets. That is, an item that will be changed in some way.

Comment: It may help to know *what* is changing in your context. A star typically means 'new' so it sounds like a good idea to change it.

Comment: Are the users changing something (editing) or are they coming back to something that has changed since they last saw it?

Comment: I'm curious: would a tire-iron or screwdriver be iconic enough to represent `change` without being confused for `edit`?

Comment: A huge "O". (Or am I 4 years late with this joke?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the audience's math & science background, a delta (Δ) can evoke the concept of change.

Comment: +1 because the audience if probably software developers.

Answer (score 10):

If it is change in terms of editing something, I would say a pencil. This is an incredibly common icon for edit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes i agree with the pencil icon, but this will be good if you place pencil over the object icon.

Like ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about a hammer? A hammer implies work to be done and can be used for both building and tearing down. (So it's analogous to a pencil, which can write and erase.)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to use the word "Change" and no icon at all.

Some concepts can't be fit into a 16x16 space. In fact, there are very little icons around that are immediately clear to [the user].

Comment: "Change" does not fit in a 14x14 block in any legible way, additionally it ends up being language specific. An icon breaks language barriers.

Comment: Then you should update the design to not use an icon and translate for every supported language.

Comment: I don't control the design of the page, I can only control what icon is shown. Even if I could change the design, icons are more appropriate for this instance. Translating for every supported language is *more* work compared to using icons which need no translation. Your advice is terrible.